# Why every single dc.barChart example groups on dimension?

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, dc.js, crossfilter

My mental image of crossfilter is that you

1. create your dimension over the variable you wish to study, and
2. create "bins" over that dimension, i.e. `group()`.

I want to create a bar chart where every bar represents a range e.g. `0<x<10`, `10<x<20`, so naturally I create a `.dimension((datapoint) => datapoint.x)`, and groups like:

```
dimension.group((x) => {
   if (x<10) return "<10";
   if (x>10 && x<20) return "10<x<20";
   /* and so on */
});
```

Now I struggle getting this dimension and group into a bar chart.
Every single `ordinal` `dc.barChart` example I've come across **does the grouping inside the dimension**. The analogy in my example would be:

```
.dimension((datapoint) => {
   if (datapoint.x<10) return "<10";
   if (datapoint.x>10 && datapoint.x<20) return "10<x<20";
   /* and so on */
});
/* and then */
...group().reduceCount();
```

This feels backwards and wrong, and forces me to create additional, "custom" dimensions that are more or less useless outside the scope of the bar chart.

How would I feed "my" approach into a minimal, really simple `dc.barChart`?

Answer (score 1):

So this turned out to be a wild goose chase.

It turns out you can easily reuse dimensions and do the binning in the group function. The simplest way I've found is to define your thresholds in an array, e.g. `var thresholds = [-1000,-100,0,100,1000];` and pass the followin as the group function:

```
...group((datapoint) => d3.bisectLeft(thresholds, datapoint)-1); // -1 with .centerBar(false) will display things in the right bin
```

Also make sure you pass an ordinal scale to `dc.barChart.x(d3.scale.ordinal()...)`. The reason I didn't get it to work in the first place (other than my d3 version 3.0.3 didn't play nicely with dc2.2) was that I omitted `.xUnits((a) => thresholds.map((d)=>d.toString()))`.

Now for the wild goose chase part... There's a big reason you don't want to do this, and instead go for the more unorthodox approach of defining your bins in the `.dimension` function: **brushing!**

Brushing requires a quantitative scale, and I've found no way to tap into dc.js internal brushing procedure to do the translation between the brush and my xUnits.

Comment: Yes, the dimension defines what you will filter on, and the group defines the aggregation. (As such, naturally the group must be more granular than the dimension.) If you do it the way you have described, you will end up filtering partial bins, which is not usually what you want.